# How to copy image from resources to disk

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I added image to my solution. Changed compilation action property to resource and don't copy. Application in first run check is directories and files are existing if not they are created. My application needs default image of object. So thats why I added image to solution. Now how I can copy it to specific disk location.
I written this from samples which I founded.

```
if (!File.Exists(path_exe + "\\images\\drinks\\defaultIMG.jpg"))
{
    using (var resource =  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Data\\defaultIMG.jpg"))
    {
         using (var file = new FileStream(path_exe + "\\images\\drinks\\defaultIMG.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
         {
               resource.CopyTo(file);
         }
}
```

}

But this creates only empty file.

Comment: Are you getting the `resource` stream correctly?

Answer (score 8):

I Think the easiest way is:

```
 Properties.Resources.defaultIMG.Save(path_exe + "\\images\\drinks\\defaultIMG.jpg");
```

Where defaultIMG is your Image resource name.

Comment: it gives me `project_name.Properties.Resources.resource_name.**get** returned null`

Answer (score 1):

I found sample of code on http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/40e97e/saving-an-embedded-file-in-C-Sharp/ It works good

```
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Zeszycik.Data.defaultIMG.jpg");
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("new.jpg", FileMode.CreateNew);
for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
     fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
fileStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your GetManifestResourceStream () returning null? GetManifestResourceStream always accepts the resource name in the following format:

```
<namespace>.<path in project>.<filename>
```

In your case, if the namespace is Company.Application and the resource file path is "Resources/defaultIMG.jpg", you should call GetManifestResourceStream as

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Company.Application.Resources.defaultIMG.jpg")
```

If you're not sure about the actual resource name within the assembly, view the list of resources embedded within the assembly with the following code:

```
foreach( string resourceName in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames() ) {
  MessageBox.Show(resourceName);
}
```

So, your code should be something like

```
if (!File.Exists(path_exe + "\\images\\drinks\\defaultIMG.jpg"))
{
    using (var resource =  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("YourNamespace.Resources.defaultIMG.jpg"))
    {
         using (var file = new FileStream(path_exe + "\\images\\drinks\\defaultIMG.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
         {
               resource.CopyTo(file);
         }
}
```

I'm assuming you've set the "Bulid Action" for your image resource to "Embedded resource".

For more information, see Microsoft [.NET Framework Resource Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950960.aspx).

Comment: I get exeption in this line `var file = new FileStream(path_exe + "\\images\\drinks\\defaultIMG.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))` But I found other way to save my file to disk.